# First insert into a static STL set causes Unhandled exception 0xC0000005: Access violation to be thrown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, stl, set

so I am working in VS 2008 with C++ for an embedded environment(ARM processor). I've built a medium sized project for my company. It has thus far been a windows application. I was asked to change it to a console application because that makes more sense for this application. I had no real reason for making it a windows application... At first, I just changed the appropriate settings (I think) in VS and then rebuilt. It built fine, but then I got the exception quoted in the title each time I tried to run the program. I want to emphasize that the program was working perfectly before I switched it to a console application. I did do a full clean and rebuild of the entire solution as well.

I thought that this was probably just a problem with me manually changing the settings, so I made a new project that was set to be a console app and plugged all of the source/other associated projects into that. This builds fine as well once I got all of the different projects in the solution linked together correctly, but the same error comes up.

When the program crashes, it stops at the insert command in the following method:

```
template<class Elem>
Node<Elem>* Node<Elem>::addChild(const Elem& value)
{
    Node<Elem>* newNode = new Node(value);
    newNode->m_pParentNode = this;
    m_childList.push_back(newNode);
    m_sNodeSet.insert(newNode);
    return newNode;
}
```

The m_sNodeSet is there to enforce the rule that each node in the tree must be unique. The error occurs the first time that this addChild method is called. At this time, the m_sNodeSet is of size zero and needs to allocate some memory. But the exception thrown is Access Violation, not Bad Alloc as might be expected. I did try adding a m_sNodeSet.get_allocator().allocate(5) before the insert statement to see if that would do anything, but the same exception is thrown. The m_sNodeSet is a static member variable, if that makes a difference.

This Node class is a custom tree object I have created. I have not changed anything in this tree project for weeks and it has been working fine. I don't think that I am throwing anything at this tree project that it hasn't seen before and performed perfectly with, so I don't think the problem lies with the tree project itself.

I am certain that this is not an issue of accessing STL containers across library boundaries  either. This error is occurring within the operations of a single static library.

I feel like there must be some setting that still needs to be changed in my solution to make this work properly. There are several projects in the solution, one DLL, one LIB, and one EXE. The tree is a fourth project, but that one is simply put into the appropriate projects' "additional includes." I only changed the EXE so that it would execute as a console app.

If you all have any inklings on what could be the problem here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the function?

Comment: Is the code possibly called from some other static construction in  another file? Before m_sNodeSet is initialized?

Comment: Does this help [What is the static initialization order fiasco?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

Comment: @BoPersson It seems like that is likely to be the issue. I'll investigate further and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have declared:

```
// Global scope
// > (quote)The m_sNodeSet is a static member variable,
std::set<Node<Elem>*>   Node<Elem>::m_sNodeSet;
```

Personal note: the prefix `m_` usually is a donator of a member variable (not a static member). Thus you are going to confuse a lot of people using this prefix.

If `m_sNodeSet` is a static member **and** the above code is being run **before main** then you potentially have a problem with initialization order. This is trivial to resolve (see below). Otherwise you have some memory corruption.

```
class Node
{

    // Remove this line
    // static std::set<Node*>   m_sNodeSet;
    // Replace with this code
    static std::set<Node*>&  getNodeSet()
    {
        static std::set<Node*>   sNodeSet;
        return sNodeSet;
    }
    // Replace all references to m_sNodeSet with getNodeSet()
}
```

This works because inside the method `getNodeSet()` the variable `sNodeSet` is static and thus created on first use and remains alive for the length of the program. Each call will return a reference to the same object. Because it is created on first call it is guaranteed to be alive (and fully constructed) when returned to the usage point.

Comment: It works! But I am not sure exactly what was going wrong. It was obviously because that static member was not being initialized. But why? The exception was being thrown in the context of main. I suppose that something about my build order changed with this minor project transition and that did it. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: If your code was running after main. Then I suspect this is not the problem. But that some other global object being constructed after m_sNodeSet was overwritting it. By changing the code above you have merly moved things around and the old bad code is still in there overwritting stuff it is just not as visible as before. I think an audit of all your global variables is your best place to start.